# Is there a way to retrieve full cli query from an action made with GUI console in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to get cli command for role creation in AWS.

But it is more intuitive to create a role using AWS GUI console. So I want to create a role with console and then retrieve a full cli command for creating a role with the same attributes.

Does AWS has this option?

Comment: No. Not yet. :)

Comment: Not ideal, but perhaps you could grab the original API call details from CloudTrail and then work out the equivalent CLI command.